# Why Convolutional NN kernel size is often selected as a square matrix

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

Given a filter of shape `(f1, f2, depth)`, what's the implications if `f1 != f2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square filter is often selected just because there's no preference in which direction a pattern can be found. For example, it can be a horizontal or a vertical line, both can be important features in an image and the network should capture any of those, if they are important. In other words, you might want your network to be *symmetric*.

Asymmetric filters became much more popular in the last years, after they were successfully used in [Inception network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842). The idea is that `n x n` filter has the same receptive field as a sequence of `1 x n` and `n x 1` convolutions (called *effective receptive field*, see [CS231n tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#layerpat) for details), but the latter requires less floating point operations and stores fewer parameters. The architecture is still symmetric in both directions (vertical patterns can be discovered as easily as horizontal ones), but the trick makes it more efficient.

Here's a picture of inception module from [Inception v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567):

[image: inception-module]

In smaller applications, where this kind of optimization isn't critical, there's no big reason to go with such complex architectures and simply use `n x n` filters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not understand how the receptive field of nxn is similar to 1xn or nx1 ? -- Does it mean that the combination of 1xn and nx1 as shown in the figure make up for the nxn in combination ?

Comment: @sujay see the explanation of *effective receptive field* here - http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#layerpat

Comment: yes, thanks for the link. It makes much sense on the "latter requires less floating point operations and stores fewer parameters" now.